# Can I show card details from the Board view?

Tags: trello

When I am in a Board, looking at the cards, I would like to be able to choose to display some information from the card instead of going into each one. For some (most) boards, I'd like the to see the first few lines of the details.

For other boards, I would like to be able to define a price or cost field, and show that. Specifically, I could make a Budget board, and have items shown wit a few lines of detail, and the cost. It would let me work with cards very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Showing more info on the card front is a common feature request. Because different people might want different info on the front of the card, it's unclear how this will be implemented.

Comment: Ok ... maybe offer options and see what sticks:
the first X lines of text, or another option can be the  the ability to choose some tags. Maybe there could also be some user defined fields, with field types, that can be added to cards, and to the card front.  So, the user can choose the current default, or define their own from a combination of options.

Comment: Since descriptions use markdown, they could just look for something like "# abstract" in or at the beginning of the card, and show everything between that and "---------------" on the face of the card. That would allow a lot of flexibility with minimal complexity.